# excel - creating simple formula for several columns

Tags: excel

My Excel file contains 3 columns: Buy, Sell and price.
Each row contain number of bought/sold lots. For example if 2 lots if bought then "Buy" column contains 2 and "Sell" column is empty. Example:

```
    3   9 060,00
2       9 030,00
10      9 090,00
    1   9 160,00
    2   9 150,00
    2   9 080,00
    4   9 100,00
```

Now I want to calculate "profit". That would be "totalSell - totalBuy", i.e. for this exaple:

```
3 * 9060 + 1 * 9160 + 2 * 9150 + 2 * 9080 + 4 * 9100
- 2 * 9030 - 10 * 9090
= 240
```

I have big Excel file, how can I told excel to do this for me?

Probably my question is not programmatic enough, then probably this question can be migrated to appropiate place.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B100,C1:C100)-SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100,C1:C100)
```

where `B1:B100` - "buy",  `A1:A100` - "sell", `C1:C100` - price